# GIT - Clone local branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to using GIT having previously worked with TFS.

My question is : I need to create a few local branches of a project and chop and change between them quite often (Occasionally to the point of essentially having both projects open at once).
To achieve this I have created local branches and then cloned them into different folders.

Before I get too far into the development I just wanted to check that this approach wont cause any issues will it?

EDIT : Adding some more detail to clarify how Im working.

So, to clarify, I have a local repositopy which I have branched a few times, I have then cloned those branches (which from the comments below means that I have new repositories for those branches) Im still not understanding why it would be more difficult to merge these back into my local master. The below shows what I have.

[image]

So now my question is, if this is going to be more difficult to work with, in what way? What are the pitfalls to doing this? What steps do I need to go through to merge these changes back in to the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting another answer for the refined question.

> if this is going to be more difficult to work with, in what way? What are the pitfalls to doing this? What steps do I need to go through to merge these changes back in to the master?

Like I mentioned the comments to my first answer, each clone is a separate repository, but pointing to the same Git URI, i.e. `//[...]/project_1.git`, i.e., connected to each other **only via the `remote`**.

Using the diagram above to explain,
To update the [local-Main] with developments in [local-Bug Fixes], there are only 2 ways:

1. via command-line:

   - `push` [local-Bug Fixes] to `remote`: `git push origin bug-fixes`
   - open second instance of terminal > `cd` to [local-Main]
   - update git index of [local-Main]: `git checkout master` > `git pull origin bug-fixes`
2. manual update:

   - copy entire contents of [local-Bug Fixes]: `Ctrl + A` > `Ctrl + C`
   - open new Explorer window > navigate to [local-Main] > Overwrite contents: `Ctrl + A` > `Ctrl + V`
   - update git index of [local-Main]: `git add .` > `git commit`

Comment: If I'd thought about it in advance I'd have use option 2 - with hindsight it would have been much easier!

Answer (score 0):

> cloned them into different folders

Having two different folders will make incorporating changes from one into another difficult, and almost nullifying the use of `Git`.

Having said that, I follow this workflow myself for some of my ruby projects

---- EDIT ----

Demonstration:

Clone the project into `C:/Projects/repo` and `C:/Projects/repo_copy`
Checkout to a *new* branch `demo` and make a change in `~repo/`

In a new terminal window, navigate to `~repo_copy/` and try to checkout the `demo` branch created in `~repo/` **You won't be able to. The `demo` branch doesn't exist there.**

Comment: Really? In what way would it be difficult, would it not just be a merge?

Comment: say clone1 is in `C:/repo/` and clone2 in `C:/repo_copy/`.. they're two different repositories even though they point to the same Git URI

Comment: I think I was updating my question as you were updating your answer!
That makes sense, I dont think thats exactly the problem I have, 

I am not creating more branches in the clones, I suppose my thinking was that I would be able to check into the clones (Feature1/Feature2/Bug Fix in the example above) and then push those changes back into the local master, then from there push those back into the remote repo?

Thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it was a bit more awkward than normal, but not by much.

The process was :
 1. In the cloned repo of one of the feature branches commit everything and then push into the main repo. that put the code from the cloned repo into the main repo in the feature branch.
 2. Merge the feature branch into master.
 3. Resolve conflicts
 4. Commit
 5. Push

So other than the initial push from the cloned repo (and a nightmare of conflicts) the process isnt that much different - I agree with the above though - I would suggest avoiding this approach (I certainly will be)